# Displaying subsites in Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, page-layout, sub-site

Is there a code which I can use to display subsites in Page Layout at my desired position?
I want to display list of subsites with hyperlinks in Page Layout. I don't want to use current navigation or top navigation.

**EDIT**

```
<?
foreach(SPWeb web in siteCollection.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
{
     Response.Write(web.title);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478651.aspx) method?

```
foreach(SPWeb web in siteCollection.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
{
    //add the web title and url as link to your collection
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use it in Page Layout? I tried the code as shown in EDIT above but it doesn't display anything. Please have a look.